# Errors when installing Google Football on Mac

Tags: python-3.x, boost

I am trying to install [Google Football](https://github.com/google-research/football) on a Mac running Catalina 10.15.7. and Xcode 12.0  I have followed the instructions shown on the web site to install the required packages using Homebrew but when I try to run the software using the following command:

```
python3 -m gfootball.play_game --action_set=full
```

I get the following messages:

```
WARNING:root:Looks like game engine is not compiled, please run:
WARNING:root:  pushd /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gfootball_engine && cmake . && make -j `nproc` && popd
WARNING:root:  pushd /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gfootball_engine && ln -s libgame.so _gameplayfootball.so && popd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 185, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gfootball/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from gfootball.env import scenario_builder
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gfootball/env/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from gfootball.env import config
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gfootball/env/config.py", line 24, in <module>
    import gfootball_engine as libgame
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gfootball_engine/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from _gameplayfootball import *
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gfootball_engine/_gameplayfootball.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gfootball_engine/_gameplayfootball.so: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x03
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gfootball_engine/_gameplayfootball.so: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x03
```

Following the guidance shown in the messages I then run:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gfootball_engine /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gfootball_engine ~/Desktop
Using Python: 3.8.6
-- Could NOT find Boost: missing: python3-py38 (found /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.73.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.73.0"))
python3-py38 not found. Trying other names.
-- Could NOT find Boost: missing: python-py38 (found /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.73.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.73.0"))
python-py38 not found. Trying other names.
-- Found Boost: /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.73.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.73.0") found components: python38 
Using python_boost: python38
-- Found Boost: /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.73.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.73.0") found components: thread system filesystem python38 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gfootball_engine
zsh: command not found: nproc
[  0%] Built target managerslib
[  0%] Built target systemscommonlib
[  2%] Built target loaderslib
[  5%] Built target typeslib
[  8%] Built target datalib
[ 14%] Built target utilslib
[ 20%] Built target menulib
[ 28%] Built target gui2lib
[ 40%] Built target baselib
[ 50%] Built target systemsgraphicslib
[ 62%] Built target scenelib
[ 64%] Built target blunted2
[ 88%] Built target gamelib
[100%] Built target game
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gfootball_engine ~/Desktop
```

I have checked that nproc is installed ( using pip3 list ) but I am not sure why it can't be found. When I use the advice shown in the second warning message:

```
pushd /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gfootball_engine && ln -s libgame.so _gameplayfootball.so && popd
```

I get the following message:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gfootball_engine /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gfootball_engine /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gfootball_engine ~/Desktop
ln: _gameplayfootball.so: File exists
```

The 'File exists' message is suggesting that the compiled game engine is in the wrong folder but I am not sure. I have checked that number of folders and everything seems to be in place for example I am using the version of python in the Homebrew folder e.g. python@3.8.

I am new to Python so it is a very likely that I have got myself into a muddle which compiling and folders. Grateful for any help on where to look next to resolve this problem - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation I found that as predicted I got myself in a muddle. There are two ways to install the module gfootball. The first way is to use pip3:

```
pip3 install gfootball
```

The second way is to build gfootball from the GitHub repository then use:

```
pip3 install .
```

from within the folder it is built in. However I still get the same error for both ways.

Comment: I posted a more specific question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64213449/error-messages-when-running-the-python-module-gfootball - where a reply pointed me in the direction of https://github.com/google-research/football/issues/226.  The advice that I received during the discussion resolved problem. I had a packages installed from other sources e.g. python38 and cmake which I deleted and then reinstalled using brew. The gfootball package is now working on my Mac. Big thanks to everybody that helped me with this problem.