# Error messages when running the Python module gfootball

Tags: python

I am trying to install the python module gfootball from the [Google Research Football Environment](https://github.com/google-research/football).  After following the installation instructions shown on the web site for a Mac ( I am using macOS High Sierra ( 10.13.6 ) and Xcode 9.4 ) I tested the setup using the the following:

```
# test_gfootball.py

import gfootball.env as football_env

env = football_env.create_environment(env_name="academy_empty_goal_close")

env.reset()

env.close()
```

But I get the following errors:

```
File "test_gfootball.py", line 5, in <module>
    env = football_env.create_environment(env_name="academy_empty_goal_close")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gfootball/env/__init__.py", line 182, in create_environment
    scenario_config = config.Config({'level': env_name}).ScenarioConfig()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gfootball/env/config.py", line 98, in __init__
    self.NewScenario()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gfootball/env/config.py", line 153, in NewScenario
    self._scenario_cfg = scenario_builder.Scenario(self).ScenarioConfig()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gfootball/env/scenario_builder.py", line 62, in __init__
    scenario.build_scenario(self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gfootball/scenarios/academy_empty_goal_close.py", line 33, in build_scenario
    builder.AddPlayer(-1.0, 0.0, e_PlayerRole_GK)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gfootball/env/scenario_builder.py", line 108, in AddPlayer
    player = Player(x, y, role, lazy, controllable)
TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'NoneType'
```

I have worked through the files named in the error message but as far as I can see everything seems to be okay. I suspect that there is something wrong with the call using “env_name” - maybe it can’t find the scenario - "academy_empty_goal_close.

What more should I check to find the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a known issue with some Conda environments: https://github.com/google-research/football/issues/156

Comment: Followed the suggestions discussed on the link shown above including the creation of a virtual environment for the installation but still get the same error messages.  I have checked that there is no clash between installed modules using MacPorts e.g. boost and pip3 but there is still no success.

Comment: Followed up on discussion at the link posted by previous comment. I deleted the packages installed from other sources e.g. python38, cmake etc. and used the packages installed by brew - the gfootball module is now working.